# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error in ts-node while modules are CommonJS

Tags: typescript, ts-node

The main cause of "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error is non-CommonJS modules (`compilerOptions.module` in **tsconfig.json**), but I got same error with `"module": "CommonJS"`.

Initially, my **tsconfig.json** was:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "baseUrl": "./01-Source",
    "paths": {
      "@EnterpriseBusinessRules/*": [ "./BusinessRules/Enterprise/*"],
      // Other aliases
    }
  }
}
```

but with this config, **ts-node** will not understand the aliases and it will be error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@EnterpriseBusinessRules/XXX/NNN'
```

Alhgough the ts-node does not understrand the alieses, it understands the `import`.
To solve the aliaases issue, I added

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": { /* */ },
  "ts-node": {
    "require": [
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ]
  }
}
```

part to **tsconfig.json* and now error is

```
import {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I know that inside `ts-node` group we can overwrite the `compilerOptions` like:

```
{
   "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "require": [
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ]
  }
}
```

but the **module** is already **CommonJS** and **esModuleInterop** is already **true**, so I must not to overwrite it (but even is to try, nothing change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the cause was not installed **ts-node**.
I executed my **.ts** file by **nodemon** which delgates the executing of **ts-node** when target file is **.ts**, but **ts-node** must be installed.